# In Wpf how to avoid/disable mouse hover a button highlight color?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I wonder if there is a way to do it for all the future buttons and other controls or do i need to make a solution for each control/button ? And how to do it ?

I want to disable the mouse hove highlight.

```
 <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Start Watching" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,241,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" RenderTransformOrigin="0.484,-0.066" Height="30" FontSize="16" Background="#FFFB0000" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
             <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="14,175,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="644"/>
             <Button Content="Browse" Margin="673,175,18,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.111,0.769" Height="30" FontSize="16"/>
```

Comment: The mouse over effects are defined in the control's template. You must provide a custom ControlTemplate to change the visual behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it to your ResourceDictionary:

```
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="4,2" 
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                        CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And since Style has no **key** it will be on **all the buttons**

Comment: it's working. now the when the mouse is over the button the button is a bit growing by size. is there a way to avoid/disable it too ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a style. if you want it to be applied through your whole app, you'll need to put it into your "app.xaml" file (within an application.Resources).

Bellow is an example of how to do it. I added some stuff like setters to illustrate that you can add properties, you could also add triggers and many things.

Not setting a "x:key" to your style will make them the default one **(thus overriding the basic one)**, as the one below, if you wish to have a collection of styles, give them keys.

```
`<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor"
                Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>`
```